# how to make webpack use shared node modules in the parent directory

Tags: node.js, webpack, serverless-framework

I want to use shared node modules which is kept in the parent directory. I have the following folder structure:

- parent directory

  - node_modules
  - company

    - serverless.yml
    - handler.js
    - webpack.config

I have to use webpack to create packages and upload into `aws-lamda`. But the webpack is looking for node modules. But I am getting the following error:

```
Overriding the webpack directory in serverless-webpack since it uses v1 version of webpack...
cp: cannot stat 'node_modules/webpack': No such file or directory
```

How can I make webpack.config point to the node_modules in the parent directory?

Comment: have you runned npm install without any errors occurring ?

Comment: I want to use a shared node modules which is in the parent directory

Comment: That does not look like a webpack error, but like a shell script error, where you try to `cp` a file that doesn't exist. Also webpack will happily look into the parent `node_modules` if it wasn't found in the `node_modules` of the current directory, unless configured otherwise. Can you show us the script you're running?

Answer (score 1):

if you read the NodeJS require documentation you are highly encouraged to use local node_modules folders even if your packages require have the same dependencies.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Alternatively your can work with `NODE_PATH` , notice that require will first look into local `node_modules` then start looking into other folders so try to delete local `node_modules`

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list of absolute paths, then Node.js will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere. (Note: On Windows, NODE_PATH is delimited by semicolons instead of colons.)

Since webpack exposes many module resolving options  https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html

> Resolving a module path
>   For resolving a module Resolve first gathers all search directories for modules from Webpack’s context directory. This process is similar to the node.js resolving process, but the search directories are configurable with the configuration option resolve.modulesDirectories. In addition to this the directories in the configuration option resolve.root are prepended, and directories in the configuration option resolve.fallback are appended.